# Mailgun with Laravel 5.1 get 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

Today i tryed to implement mailgun to Laravel 5.1 but when i try to use it i get the following [error](https://gyazo.com/90418f1216fb0aa14e6eeb14f6d20fdd).

I don't know how to solve the problem. but as you can see in my [configs](be correct: https://gyazo.com/077e0d035c82e39abba5cc9372560753) it should.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to connect to mailgun, i.e. the controller/etc.

Comment: Can you inline the pictures?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now. It seems like it is trying to send a POST request to https://api.mailgun.net/v3//messages.mime which returns 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use mailgun, I use smtp credentials. You can take them on page like this - http://take.ms/ChjOQ. Then set username and password and then everything must work. Where you use mailgun domain?